# can't understand _e function well

Tags: theme-development

```
<?php _e( $text, $domain ) ?>

$domain
```

(string) (optional) Domain to retrieve the translated text
Default: 'default

can't understand  the second argument well. when i custom a theme, where the $domain's value shows on the theme, what value should i give it to.? could i write the $domain part optionally?i see some themes using its theme name as the $domain. but the document says **Domain** to retrieve the translated text.it's not a domain. why? some using other strings which doesn't have any relevance of the theme?

Answer (score 2):

`$domain` is the unique identifier for retrieving translated strings.

It is set in functions.php

`<?php load_theme_textdomain( $domain, $path ) ?>`

ex:

`load_theme_textdomain('my_theme', get_template_directory() . '/languages');`

`<?php _e( 'Translate this text', 'my_theme' ) ?>`

If you don't have a translation file but want't to make it translatable just define the textdomain.

`load_theme_textdomain('my_theme');`

Comment: if i don't have the languages file. how do i do?

Comment: it is not absolutely necessary to have a languages file, for example the translation plugin WPML can also translate the strings within the Dashboard, without the need for a .mo file.